# Polymorphic Association in Active Admin Not Passing All Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations, formtastic

I created a Polymorphic Association in Active Admin for the creation of Keyword associated with Industry. I can display the association fine in Active Admin (the association was created in the console) but when I Update and create New, only the keyword parameters gets passed. If I go back to the console and update, the updated data is properly displayed in Active Admin.

I never get an error.

I have:

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :keywords, :keywords_attributes

  # Associations
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :companies
  has_many :users
  has_many :keywords, as: :keyable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :profile_id, :active,
                  :keyable_attributes, :rating,
                  :keyable_id, :keyable_industry

  # Associations
  belongs_to :profile # FK
  belongs_to :keyable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keyable

  attr_accessor :keyable_industry

  def keyable_industry
    self.keyable.id if self.keyable.is_a? Industry
  end
end


ActiveAdmin.register Keyword do
index do
    column :name
    column :active
    column :rating
    column "Keyword Group", :keyable
    column :keyable_type
    default_actions
end
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Conference Detail" do
        f.input :name
        f.input :active
        f.input :rating
        f.input :keyable_industry
    end

    f.inputs "Industry" do
        f.input :keyable_industry, label: "Industry", 
        :as => :select,
        :collection => Industry.all.map {|i| [i.name]},
        :include_blank => false
    end
    f.actions
  end
 end

Development Log Output
Started PUT "/admin/keywords/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-13 11:41:32 -0400
Processing by Admin::KeywordsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"nnbMIHy1YndWNOKyF+LSABYyeQMpKQAiTyqGbL2sq3g=", "keyword"=>  {"name"=>"test", "active"=>"1", "rating"=>"1", "keyable_industry"=>"Agriculture &   Forestry"}, "commit"=>"Update Keyword", "id"=>"2"}
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Keyword Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."id" = $1   LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
 (0.7ms)  BEGIN
 (1.1ms)  UPDATE "keywords" SET "name" = 'test', "updated_at" = '2013-09-13   15:41:32.287147' WHERE "keywords"."id" = 2
 (2.9ms)  COMMIT
 Redirected to http://blog.dev/admin/keywords/2
 Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got this to work not not sure if its the best solution. Opinions welcome.

To review, I have the following for my Models:

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :keywords, :keywords_attributes

# Associations
 has_many :profiles
 has_many :companies
 has_many :users
 has_many :keywords, as: :keyable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords

end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :name, :profile_id, :active,
  :keyable_attributes, :rating,
  :keyable_id, :keyable_industry, :keyable_type

 # Associations
  belongs_to :profile # FK
  belongs_to :keyable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keyable

  has_many :conference_keywordeds
  has_many :conferences, through: :conference_keywordeds

end
```

So for my ActiveAdmin Keyword Controller I created a hidden value for Industry to pass that value. So now I now have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Keyword do
  index do
    column :name
    column :active
    column "Keyword Type",      :keyable_type
    column "Keyword Group",     :keyable

    default_actions

end

show do |keyword|
    attributes_table do
        row :id
        row :name
        row :created_at
        row :updated_at
        row :active
        row :keyable_id
        row :keyable_type

    end
    active_admin_comments
end

form do |f|
    f.inputs "Conference Detail" do
        f.input :name
        f.input :active
        f.input :keyable,
                :label => "Keyword Group", as: :select, 
                :collection => Industry.all, 
                :include_blank => false
        f.input :keyable_type, as: :hidden, 
                :input_html => { :value => "Industry"}
         end
    f.actions
    end
  end
```

Comment: protip: when you give a `:collection` option, `:select` is the default input type, so you don't need `as: :select`